# Single variable statement while loops in python

Tags: python, while-loop

```
a = int(input("Give me the first number? "))
b = int(input("Give me the second number? "))
r=a%b

while r:
    a=b
    b=r
    r = a%b

print('The HCF is ', b)
```

This is the solution to a coding question in my textbook which asks us to,
 "find the HCF of a number via Euclid's division lemma". 
My code was the same except for the condition of the while loop.

My condition was : while r == 0 
Textbook condition : while r

My code was giving me a bug. Can someone explain the textbook condition as I have not seen a variable being used as a statement.

Comment: `while r` means "while r is not 0". And `while r == 0` means "while r is 0" - so your code is the exact opposite of what it should be

Comment: Since `0` is interpreted as `False` in a boolean context, `while r == 0` is the same as `while not r`.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use pretty much every in-built object as a condition : 
If it is a number it will check if this number is different from 0
If it is a list, a dictionary or a set it will check if the object is not empty

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a `while` loop, Python will convert the given condition to its bool counterpart (think `bool(r)`). In python, everything (in a boolean context )evaluates to `True` unless it is `False` or *empty*.

*Empty* means things like `[]`, `{}`, and of course `0`. So, all numbers except for `0` will return `True` in the `while` loop, meaning that it'll only end at `r == 0`